# Excel Worksheet_Change event triggering when deleting row

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling

I have an excel worksheet with some `vba` code that when i change a specific cell it automatically sets the date of today into the cell next to it.

That all works good, but when i delete an entire row that's above that specific cell it changes the date automatically to the date of today.

This is the code i use to automatically the change the cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.Sheets("Example").Range("H10: H306, M10: M306, R10: R306, W10: W306, AB10: AB306, AG10: AG306"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
        Sheets("Example").Unprotect
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        Sheets("Example").Protect
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Is someone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some tests on Range `Target`, to avoid executing the code 
(with `Goto` or rather `Exit Sub`) :

- `Target.Cells.Count > 1`
- `Target.Rows.Count > 1`
- `Target.Columns.Count > 1`

You can use theses tests at the start of the Sub or with `If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then`

So your code could be :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer

If Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.Sheets("Example").Range("H10: H306, M10: M306, R10: R306, W10: W306, AB10: AB306, AG10: AG306"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
        Sheets("Example").Unprotect
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        Sheets("Example").Protect
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad I could help! ;) @Graaf